# What is eating my orange trees?

Tags: trees, diagnosis, pest-control, citrus

I have 3 navel orange trees in my backyard and the leaves are being eaten by something.  What is it that is eating the leaves, and what can I do to prevent this?

Comment: Hi user3503, Welcome to the site! Can you put up a link to some photos, and describe the problem a little better? There are too many possibilities to make an accurate diagnosis without that.

Comment: Ok I will Get a couple pics. & return thanks

Comment: This question cannot be properly answered without a photograph, and possibly more detail.